# Conditional validation if another validation is valid

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation

I have the following three validations in a model in my rails app:

```
  validates_presence_of :reset_code, message: 'Please enter your reset code'
  validates_length_of :reset_code, is: 4, message: 'Your reset code should be 4 digits'
  validates_format_of :reset_code, with: /\A[0-9]{4}\z/, message: 'Please enter a valid reset code'
```

I only want to fire the second and third validations if the first is valid (as there is no point in telling the user the reset code isn't the correct length or format if they haven't entered one at all).

So something along the lines of:

```
validates_length_of :reset_code, is: 4, message: 'Your reset code should be 4 digits', :if => :reset_code.present?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use new the new validation syntax, and provide a simple `if:` condition:

```
  validates :reset_code, length: { is: 4 },
    message: 'Your reset code should be 4 digits',
    if: -> { reset_code.present? }

  validates :reset_code, format: { with: /\A[0-9]{4}\z/ },
    message: 'Please enter a valid reset code',
    if: -> { reset_code.present? }
```

Comment: Can I achieve this with the older syntax?

Comment: @Cameron http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Validations/HelperMethods.html

Comment: Ah, it was because I had used `:if =>` rather than `if: ->`

Comment: What if I want the third to only fire if the first and second have passed? So instead of checking if it is present, check the validation itself is valid?

Comment: Could I just do: `if: -> { validates_length_of.valid? }`

Comment: @Cameron The problem is that you're *doing* all three. Just do the `format` one. It makes no sense to validate the same field three times for the *same* data. Checking present *and* length *and* format is three times redundant.